# increment a field in moongose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to increment a field automatically on update with condition.

I have two Schemas:

```
var History = new Schema({
   action : {type: String},
   eventType : {type : String}
})
```

And:

```
 var Quote = new Schema({
           name : {type: String},
           email : {type: String},
           quoteNumber : {type: Number}
           history: [History]
        });
```

`quoteNumber` is the field which I want to increment by 1 as soon as a record `histroy` field gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the $inc operator in MongoDB. So whichever function you use to update history, for example:

```
db.collection.update({name: "foo"}, {$push: {history: "Log History"}, $inc:{quoteNumber : 1})
```

Read up on it here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

However, since history is an array, you could just get the length of the array as well.